# How can I change the material of an object from a different scene with a button?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and to get the hang of the program I tried making the Roll a Ball game from the unity classes and expanding it (Adding levels, a pause menu, etc.). Currently, I am trying to make a menu where you can choose the colour of the ball you control. Trying to search it on Google resulted in a dozen different solutions, none of which were of help. It would be appreciated if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a reference to ball `GameObject` (or at least his `MeshRenderer` component)

```
public GameObject ball;
```

Then you need to create a Menu with different buttons that correspond every button to the `Material` you want, simplified:

```
public Material newBallMaterial;
```

To change ball material you have to overwrite his material like this:

```
ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newBallMaterial;
```

As derHugo pointed, if the trully problem is to maintain the reference between scenes, try to use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) to maintain objects between scenes. Use it like this:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObjectToMaintainTheReference);
```

Comment: So I'ld guess OP's main question is: How do I get a reference to an object from another scene ;)

Comment: @derHugo you're right, I've focus on the description, not the title, thanks